# log4j - compress log file to gz on fly

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is it possible to setup log4j to create gziped log files without creating intermediate .log files? There are several rolling strategies (rolling by date, etc), but they creates unzipped files first.

Comment: log4j generates logs as per your rolling period.i dont think is there any kind of strategies for your need.you have do it manually

Comment: You would want to have at least the current log, as even if you made your own appender it would be expensive to write to zipped file directly. You would have to keep the log in memory (risky in case of Jvm Halt) and then write out the zip file. why would you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to solve this task using this Writer: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/coyote/http11/filters/FlushableGZIPOutputStream.html
and a code like

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FlushableGZIPOutputStream(newFileOutputStream(logFileName), LINES_TO_FLUSH));
appender.setWriter(writer);
```

It works but there are some drawbacks: compression is lower and it is not always possible to unzip this file. So I returned back to rotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can create you own Appender extending org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender and overriding
the current logic by implementing your own optimized implementation version. Zip current file and discard rolling it to another log file (default implementation of RollingFileAppender). Example:

```
log4j.appender.{name}=br.com.sample.MyZipRollingFileAppender
```

You can "google" and search implementation examples using java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream or java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream to zip the current file.

Answer (score 0):

You may try org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy:

```
<appender...>
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/wombat/log.%d{yyyy-MM}**.gz**"/>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```